# looping through a list of string items and returning those that contain a substring in python

Tags: python, string, list, nltk

I am attempting to loop through a list of sentences and only pull items in the list that contain a sub-string (keyword), when using return instead of yield in my function i get back a list of characters vs yield i get full sentences but I know it is a generator and want a full list of every sentence that contains the word. Is it the .find() causing the issue or is there a better way to pull from a list of string items?

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
import pandas as pd
f= open("filename.txt").read()
sent_list = sent_tokenize(f)

hunt = "youth" #keyword i'm searching for
def hunter(sent):
    for term in sent:
        if term.find(hunt) is not -1:
            yield term

complete_lst = [term for term in hunter(sent_list)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'key_term_sentences':complete_lst})
```

Comment: If you just use return instead of yield, then you will get back the first and only the first. A typical pattern is to make `hunter` a generator and then to get a list do `list(hunter(sent_list))`.

Comment: Also per the docs if you don't need the index you should just use `if hunt in term`

Comment: @BaileyParker that seemed to do the trick my goal is to ensure that every sentence containing the substring is yielded in the generator

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of bugs in your code of which not using `split` is one. After fixing that, everything works fine. Below is a working example:

```
In [31]: sent_list = ['this is first sentence for demo purposes', 
                      'this is second sentence containing youth and youthful', 
                      'this is 3rd sentence which is dummy one btw']

In [32]: hunt = 'youth'

# note that we need two `for` loops since the function takes list of sentences
In [33]: def hunter(sent_list):
    ...:     for sent in sent_list:
    ...:         for term in sent.split():
    ...:             if hunt in term:
    ...:                 yield term
    ...:                 

In [34]: list(hunter(sent_list))
Out[34]: ['youth', 'youthful']
```

---

Just to demonstrate that you can also use `term.find(hunt)` as you're using it already:

```
In [35]: def hunter(sent_list):
    ...:     for sent in sent_list:
    ...:         for term in sent.split():
    ...:             if term.find(hunt) is not -1:
    ...:                 yield term
    ...:                 

In [36]: list(hunter(sent_list))
Out[36]: ['youth', 'youthful']
```

Answer (score 0):

An even easier way would be to `.split` the each sentence into a list of individual sentences. From there you can iterate through each one, split it, and check if the word is in the sentence.

```
hunt = "youth"
def hunter(sent):
    sentences = sent.split('.')
    for each in sentences:
        check = each.split(' ')
        for word in check:
            if word = hunt:
                print each
```